# how to change location on simpleWheater.js on click?

Tags: jquery

I'm using simpleWheater.js http://simpleweatherjs.com/ to display weather for specific location.This is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Zagreb,HR',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'c',

    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2>'+weather.temp+'&deg;<i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> </h2>';
      html += '<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="wheter-info">';
      html += '<ul><li><a href=""><span class="fa fa-umbrella"> ' + weather.humidity + ' % </span> </li>';
      html += '<li><a href=""><span class="wi-wind"> '+ weather.wind.speed + ' km/h </span></li>';
      html += '<li><a href="" class="compass"><span class="wi-compass"></span>'+ weather.wind.direction +'</a></li>'
      html += '</ul></div></div>';
      html += '<div class="col-xs-12"><div id="custom-search-input"><div class="input-group col-md-12 padding-top5"><input type="text" class="padding10 search-query form-control" placeholder="'+weather.city+'"><span class="input-group-btn"><button id="search-weather" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">';
      html += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span</div></div></div>';
      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Location is now fixed but i want when user enter location and click on button search to change location and display it. I added `id` to `button` and tried this, but i dont get any alert on click.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search-weather").click(function(){
         alert("test");
      });
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: i want to enter any location....

Comment: he just need to enter city and then click on search button

Comment: i dont know...i think it will open some city if i enter some that  does not exist

Comment: **[So something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7d3fsh7k/)**

Comment: yes you can do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7d3fsh7k/)

You can just have a `textbox` where user can enter `city` and then you can write a `click event` and call the method which again gets the information of user entered city. Below is one of the ways, which you can use it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="weather"></div>
<br/>
<div class="userInput">
    <input type="text" class="city" placeholder="Enter your location"/>
</div>
<button class="js-geolocation" style="display: none;">Search</button>
<div class="error"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadWeather('Seattle',''); //@params location, woeid
    //default city on DOM load
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
  //keep this in a function so that you can call it anytime.
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.alt.temp+'&deg;C</li></ul>';  

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
}

$('.js-geolocation').on('click', function() {
    //click event to search for city
    var city=$('.city').val();//get the value from textbox
    if(city!="") //check if its null?
        loadWeather(city,'')//call the loadWeather method and pass the value entered by user
    else
        $('.error').text('Please enter a location');
        //if null entered just display an error
});
```

> **Note :** This will throw console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of null` when a city which is not found is entered and which is actually plugin error. So I would suggest you can ask for support with the author in GitHub on this feature as currently it is not supported by the plugin